# Incorporating validation data correctly in model.fit with Keras and DistilBERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I'm new to NLP and am trying to do some binary classification with DistilBERT on a Kaggle dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/nlp-getting-started/data). Everything is actually going fine, but I'm having trouble incorporating my validation data into model.fit. I just can't figure out why val_accuracy and val_loss don't appear in my epoch values. My code is below.

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification
import tensorflow as tf

#import tokenizer and pre-trained model
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

#random seed
random_seed = 42

#set random seed in tensorflow
tf.random.set_seed(random_seed)

#set random seed in numpy
np.random.seed(random_seed)

#load the raw training data
df_raw_train = pd.read_csv("data/train.csv")
#make a copy of df_raw_train
df_train = df_raw_train.copy(deep=True)

#load the raw test data
df_raw_test = pd.read_csv("data/test.csv")
#make a copy of df_raw_test
df_test = df_raw_test.copy(deep=True)

#get target name
target = 'target'

#drop columns
df_train.drop(['id','keyword','location'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_test.drop(['id','keyword','location'],axis=1,inplace=True)

#training (80%) and validation (20%) data split

df_train, df_val = train_test_split(df_train, train_size=0.8, random_state=random_seed)

#reset index
df_train, df_val = df_train.reset_index(drop=True), df_val.reset_index(drop=True)

#batch tokenize our tweet field
X_train = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(df_train.text, pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors="tf")
X_val = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(df_val.text, pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors="tf")
X_test = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(df_test.text, pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors="tf")

#obtain target
y_train = df_train['target'].to_numpy()
y_val = df_val['target'].to_numpy()

#optimize model
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
model.fit(x=X_train['input_ids'], y=y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=15, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

The epoch output looks like this:

```
Epoch 1/2
343/508 [===================>..........] - ETA: 6:30 - loss: 0.4728 - accuracy: 0.7811
```

I'd really appreciate some pointers here. Thank you, all.

Comment: Evaluation is done at the end of each epoch.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to omit the sklearn test/train split, remove `validation_data=(X_val, y_val)` from model.fit and replace with `validation_split=0.2`.